# What is the object type of load_breast_cancer() dataset in Python sklearn and what does load_breast_cancer().keys() do?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, dataset

I am fairly new to Machine Learning with Python and have been trying to understand KNN through a small project. I'm having difficulty understanding what's going on in this code.

I'm trying to understand the `load_breast_cancer()` dataset by examining the data.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer

cancer = load_breast_cancer()
print(cancer.keys())
```

So, in this code what does `print(cancer.keys())`do? I mean it's returning `dict_keys(['data', 'target', 'target_names', 'DESCR', 'feature_names'])` but `load_breast_cancer()` is not a dictionary, right? I'm thoroughly confused what's going on here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_breast_cancer.html):

> Returns:
>   data : Bunch
>   **Dictionary-like object**, the interesting attributes are: ‘data’, the data to learn, ‘target’, the classification labels, ‘target_names’, the meaning of the labels, ‘feature_names’, the meaning of the features, and ‘DESCR’, the full description of the dataset, ‘filename’, the physical location of breast cancer csv dataset (added in version 0.20).

Answer (score 0):

You can always use `type`
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type .

In your case 
`print(type(cancer))` or `print(type(cancer.keys())`

aditionally you can check if something is inherited using:

`issubclass`
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#issubclass

or using `help` 
like:

`print(help(cancer))`